# What to do with starvation tokens?

Tags: dead-of-winter

The rules state that when the players cannot feed their colony, they should place a starvation token in the food supply and decrease morale for every starvation token in the supply. What to do after that is unclear to me.

Do you lose morale after **every round** for every starvation token you have in the food supply? Is there a way to get rid of starvation tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep the starvation tokens in the food supply for the rest of the game, however, they only cause you to lose morale when you don't have enough food that round.

For example, you don't have enough food this round and you add one starvation token to the food supply but keep the food that was already in there. This causes you to lose one morale. Two rounds later, you don't have enough food again, and you add a second starvation token. This causes you to lose two morale since there are now two starvation tokens in the food supply.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to get rid of starvation tokens but they only cause a loss of morale when there is not enough to food to eat for that round. In that situation, you would lose 1 morale for each starvation token in the food supply.

This is covered in the [rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/dead-of-winter/rules.pdf) in the section that describes the Pay Food section of the Colony phase. The rules indicate that in the situation where you do not have enough food in the food supply to feed the colony, you do not remove the food, but instead add a starvation token and then decrease morale for each starvation token in the supply.

This was further confirmed in a [forum discussion on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/17288300#17288300) that involved Johnny Gilmour, one of the game designers.